# Mobile version Google Chrome on PC (for developers)

Tags: browser, emulation, desktop, simulator, mobile-browser

Could you suggest how best to test the site for Google Chrome mobile version...? I know that Opera Mobile and Mozilla Firefox are emulators for the desktop, but I have not seen this for Chrome. Maybe I'm just looking bad?

for example:

**Mozilla Firefox** - http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/ (fennec)

**Opera** - http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old question but in case someone else hit it in future;

Best solution i found is this;
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=tr

And the best part is, its working!

PS: If "adv devices" command doesn't work make sure that you have the USB driver for your phone is installed on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome Canary can be a better replacement for this purpose. I use Chrome Canary for testing purpose.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to browse mobile version of nay site using browsing agent switcher, there are browser agent switcher for all browsers, more read here about [browsing mobile version of site on desktop PC](https://talktopoint.com/browse-mobile-version-of-site-on-desktop/).

Comment: OP wanted to test how his website would look on a mobile browser using his PC, not get the mobile version of a website